# How to invert black and white with scikit-image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I read an image with [`ndimage`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html), which results in a binary image like this:

[image]

I would like to invert the image such that white turns into black, and vice versa.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
numpy.invert(close_img)
```

I use invert array. It works for me.

Comment: If your image is of dtype bool, then you can simply do ``~close_img``.

Comment: If your image is of dtype unsigned integer, you can also use `~close_img`.

Answer (score 18):

With the devel version of scikit-image (upcomming v0.13), you can use **invert()**. Example:

```
from skimage import util 
img = data.camera() 
inverted_img = util.invert(img)
```

Comment: It worked better than cv2.bitwise_not. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Here's another method using OpenCV

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('2.png')
invert = cv2.bitwise_not(image) # OR
# invert = 255 - image
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: great, verry usefull

Answer (score 4):

If your image is represented with non-negative floating point values topping out at 1.0, you can use `1 - close_image`

Comment: It can be used for images with a maximum value of 255. Just use `255 - close_image`

Answer (score 1):

I like [Pamungkas Jayuda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4287229/pamungkas-jayuda)'s anwer, but it works only on the assumption that your data is an integer. In my case, I just used simple inversion with a small value on the denominator to avoid division by zero:

```
1 / (2e5 + img)
```