# Tesseract failing to detect very simple binarized image

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using Tesseract in python with PyTesseract. My goal is to detect the characters on a screenshot. The text on the screenshot is perfectly aligned and binarization works perfectly. But the Tesseract detection rate is very poor.

I already tried:

1. Gaussian filters before and after binarization
2. Upscaling
3. Different manually selected thresholds
4. No thresholding
5. Tesseract 4.0 and 5.0 alpha

Here is my Python script:

```py
from skimage import io
import pytesseract

im = io.imread("screenshots/test.png", as_gray=True)

thresholded = im > .30
thresholded += im < 0.02

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thresholded, lang="eng"))
```

Images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRo5I.jpg

Results:

- "Dilan"
- "Free Flowing Trartic"
- "Traffic Restrictions"
- "PE Taare ones"

Comment: I believe Tesseract expects (=works best with) text to be black on white background - have you tried inverting the image, what results do you get?

Comment: That's it! It works now as expected. Thanks you very much. I didn't think of this as important factor...

Comment: For those who see this question and want to know how to invert the image, see [How to invert black and white with scikit-image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084908/how-to-invert-black-and-white-with-scikit-image)