# How to save images in inverse gray-scale?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

Can anyone tell how to save images in inverse gray-scale using scipy.misc.imsave.Using below code I'm able to save images in gray-scale mode only but I need inverse gray-scale images for my classification task

```
            data = next(generator_queues[j])

            assert data.shape == target_shape, "Shape mismatch {} vs {}".format(data.shape, args.shape)

            file_name = os.path.join(args.target, language, "{}.png".format(i))

            scipy.misc.imsave(file_name, np.squeeze(data))
```

Comment: have a look at the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28084908/how-to-invert-black-and-white-with-scikit-image)

Comment: if normalized `1 - array` else `255-array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:** `np.squeeze(255 - data)`

```
    data = next(generator_queues[j])

    assert data.shape == target_shape, "Shape mismatch {} vs {}".format(data.shape, args.shape)

    file_name = os.path.join(args.target, language, "{}.png".format(i))

    scipy.misc.imsave(file_name, np.squeeze(255 - data)) # if not normalised else 1 - data
```